# вызов хранимой процедуры Firebird и передача параметра типа date

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird

На Firebird 3 есть хранимая процедура PR_Balances(остатки на момент времени),одним входным параметром типа date. 
Когда процедуру вызываю IBExpert-ом

```
select * from PR_Balances(06.02.2019)
```

правильно выполняется
но когда из delphi вызываю

```
FDQuery1.SQL.clear;
FDQuery1.SQL.Add('select * from R_Balances('+Maskedit3.text+')'); 
FDQuery1.open;
```

выдает ошибку:

> token unknown- line 1, column 27. '0'

breakpoint показывает, что Maskedit.text правильно получает значение '01.02.2019'.

Comment: Не слушайте никого, а создавайте параметризованные запросы.

Comment: Igor, заработал решение  который  @Герман Борисов предлагал: 'select * from PR_Balances('''+Maskedit3.text+''')
Вы имели ввиду такой параметризованный запрос? 
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from PR_Balances(:A)';
FDQuery1.Params[0].AsDate:=strtodate(Maskedit3.Text); 

Этот вариант тоже работает. Есть Какая-то разница между ними?

Comment: запрос с строковыми литералами не являются параметризованными запросами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметры типа DATE, TIME и TIMESTAMP должны передаваться как строковые литералы в одинарных кавычках. Желательно еще и с префиксом типа. Также необходимо, чтобы дата была в одном из предусмотренных документацией форматов.

```
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from R_Balances(DATE'''+Maskedit3.text+''')');
FDQuery1.Open;
```

PS откуда у всех делфистов привычка писать `SQL.Clear; SQL.Add(…); … SQL.Add(…);` вместо `SQL.Text := …`?

**UPD** на всякий случай перечислю допустимые форматы даты в Firebird

- `YYYY<d>MM<d>DD`
- `DD<d>MM`
- `MM<d>DD`
- `DD<d>MM<d>YY`
- `MM<d>DD<d>YY`
- `DD<d>MM<d>YYYY`
- `MM<d>DD<d>YYYY`

где `<d>` - символ-разделитель: точка, двоеточие, запятая, минус, прямой слэш (`/`) или пробел.

Так как форматы `DD<d>MM…` и `MM<d>DD…` очень похожи, то первый используется, если разделитель точка, а второй для остальных, т.е. `DATE'01.02'` - это 1 февраля, а `DATE'01/02'` - 2 января.

Comment: А ещё лучше использовать параметры и не париться с кавычками вообще. Да и безопаснее. Про SQL.Clear не уверен, но полагаю что из какой-то "очень умной" книжки по дельфям.

Comment: @Alekcvp, Да, из книги "Хомоненко, Гофман. Delphi 7".  Там они используют и вариант  'select * from PR_Balances('+Maskedit3.text+')'); а в delphi 10.2 мне выдает ошибку.

Comment: @basti, если Delphi 7, да ещё и наших авторов, то не удивлюсь что там про BDE написано.

Comment: Зато я знаю откуда у вас привычка писать параметры в тексте SQL. Из PHP. Бедные php-программисты, столько лет безуспешно борются с sql-инъекциями, хотя даже в MySQL давным давно есть параметры в запросах.

Comment: @Eugene, такие вещи в книгах по Delphi рекомендовали еще до появления PHP, во всяком случае до его популярности.

Comment: Герман Борисов, как раз в первых книгах по Дельфи этих глупостей не было. Доказательство см. http://www.programmersclub.ru/bookdb/ Внизу можно текст книги скачать. Глава 9, динамические запросы. PHP начала широко распространятся с 1998 года. Собственно, web-программирование не воспринималось как настоящее и уровень его аудитории был крайне низким - туда шли все без малейших знаний и образования. Увы, впоследствии начали из него тащить кучу глупостей.

Answer (score 4):

Правильно - использовать параметризованный запрос.

```
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from R_Balances(:thedate');
FDQuery1.ParamByname ('thedate').AsDateTime := StrToDate (Maskedit3.text);
FDQuery1.Open;
```

Неправильно - в обоих других ответах, в том числе в том, который выбран.
facepalm

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо MaskEdit’а использовать DateTimePicker и передавать FormatDateTime(“dd.MM.yyyy”, DateTimePicker.Date)

Comment: Praddos, FormatDateTime('dd.MM.yyyy', DateTimePicker1.Date);

fdQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from PR_Balances('+datetostr(DateTimePicker1.Date)+')';

fdQuery1.Open;
та же самая ошибка: token unknown- line 1, column 27. '0'

Comment: Да перестаньте уже эти глупости тиражировать. Параметры надо задавать через параметризованные запросы.